# Java: HTML/CSS in Swing, display inline not working

Tags: java, html, css, swing

I am trying to display a complex string in a Swing JButton using HTML/CSS. I am using CSS1 attributes, which is supported by Swing. The problem is that the following causes the button title to break into 3 separate lines rather than a single line:

```
javax.swing.JButton("<html><div style='display:inline;'>regular </div><div style='background-color:#336699;color:#fff;display:inline;'>special</div><div style='display:inline;'> regular again");
```

[image]

Note that the said string works great in a browser webpage, generating a single line (no line breaks):

[image]

I tried using "float:left" and "display:inline-block" - these also have no visible effect.

Anyone have an idea why this happens and what can be done?
Please limit your answers to HTML/CSS as I do not wish to implement a special L&F or class for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well traditionally `<span>` is just like a `<div>` except it defaults to inline display. I'd try that first before messing with much else.

EDIT:

Ok so I played around with this a bit the following html works for me:

```
"<html>" + 
"regular" +
"<font style='background-color:#336699; color:#fff;'>special</font>" +
"regular again"
```

Comment: I think that's more of a comment's material and not an answer, but I'll let it slide...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it has the same effect.

Comment: No idea why the span tag doesn't work (it should dangit)  but the `<font>` tag seems to do the job.

Comment: You were correct both times, apparently: <span> also works ok, if you only make the button large enough. Apparently, Swing auto-wraps the text if the button is too narrow. This works for <span> and <font> but as I noted in my question, for some strange reason not for <div>. Strange, but at least now we have a workaround. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah it is curious that the css display property is ignored for the div. Glad it's working for you now though :)

Comment: CSS is not ignored in general in <div> - only the combination of <div> and display: is ignored, that's the strange part. <div> works correctly with other CSS attributes like color etc.

Comment: Yes I realized I spoke imprecisely first and edited my comment before you refreshed :P but quite right that it's only the display property.

Answer (score 0):

1) your Html/Css syntax isn't valid for Java6 `"` instead of `'` and vice versa

2) please your question question would be based on this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

pictures

[image] [image] [image]

code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.pushingpixels.trident.Timeline;

public class ButtonFg extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ButtonFg() {
        JButton button = new JButton("<html><div style='display:inline;"
                + "'>regular </div><div style='background-color:#336699;"
                + "color:#fff;display:inline;'>special</div>"
                + "<div style='display:inline;'> regular again");
        button.setForeground(Color.blue);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        add(button);
        final Timeline rolloverTimeline = new Timeline(button);
        rolloverTimeline.addPropertyToInterpolate(
                "foreground", Color.blue, Color.red);
        rolloverTimeline.setDuration(2500);
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                rolloverTimeline.play();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                rolloverTimeline.playReverse();
            }
        });
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(150, 150);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ButtonFg().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are simply proving what I said in my question - that the display:inline attribute apparently does not work in Swing. My question was (1) why? and (2) how to fix?. I thank you for your answer, but it does not answer these questions.